# Prove (or provide a counterexample): no pair of primitive Pythagorean triples (a,b,c) and (2a,k,c) exists.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

A primitive Pythagorean triple is an ordered set of coprime integers (a,b,c) such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Show that the system of Diophantine equations
$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$
$$4a^2+k^2=c^2$$
have no solutions.

Comment: Are $a,b,$ and $c$ coprime in your system?

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/ross2007/congnumber.pdf

Answer (score 0):

$$c^2=a^2+b^2=4a^2+k^2$$

$$k^2+3a^2=b^2$$

All solutions of this Diophantine equation are defined parameterization.

$$a=2ps$$

$$k=p^2-3s^2$$

$$b=p^2+3s^2$$

Then the amount of;

$$a^2+b^2=4p^2s^2+p^4+6p^2s^2+9s^4=p^4+10p^2s^2+9s^4$$

A square can not be.

Comment: Why $(p^2+s^2)(p^2+9s^2)$ cannot be a square?

Comment: To see $$p^4+10p^2s^2+9s^4$$ cannot be a square, the quartic curve $$y^2 = x^4+10x^2+9$$ is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve $$Y^2 = X^3+X^2-4X-4$$ which APECS reports has rank 0.  The torsion group corresponds to either $p=0$ or $s=0$.