# Rational Parameterization of $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 = d^2 + 4 b^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I want to parameterize the equation $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 = d^2 + 4 b^2$ but every avenue I go down leads to an equation I can’t solve.

I know $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ is parameterized by $(2uvk, (u^2 - v^2)k, (u^2 + v^2)k)$ so it should be as simple as:

$(u^2 + v^2)k = (p^2 + q^2)n$

$(uv)k = (2pq)n$

Or some other combination of terms, but I’m still having trouble actually solving it.

Could anyone provide some guidance?

Comment: Note that that's not the parametrization for all pythagorean triples, but only for PRIMITIVE triples. You need to include a factor of $k$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you! I fixed that in the prompt

Comment: You fixed that in one place. Can you follow through all of the changes needed?

Comment: Hint:2^2=4 

Comment: You already made it discussing triplets just bashing out that 2^2 out of $2uvk$

Comment: see if you can prove that there are no such examples with  integers $a,b,c,d \neq 0$

Comment: @Will Jagy if I construct an example then?

Comment: @HappieHappieHappie  that would be surprising

Comment: 13^2=12^2+5^2=4.6^2+5^2 anything else?

Comment: Many such exist because in PT there are 2uv factor infact c^2 has two different representation in PT and hence it works.

Comment: Suprise Suprise Suprise @WillJagy Sir Lol!!! Like a Villan I am talking. But What's correct is correct may be it's given by a Villan

Comment: @HappieHappieHappie  In the original $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 = d^2 + 4 b^2$  what are your values for $a,b,c,d$  exactly?

Comment: @HappieHappieHappie  Your example requires $c=13$  and the $4 \cdot 6^2$   says that $b = 6.$  Then $d=5.$   The thing that fails is that $c^2 - b^2 = 13^2 - 6^2 = 133. $ For your example to be legitimate you would need $a^2 = 133,$   but $133$ is not a perfect square and the resulting $a$ is not an integer.

Comment: [This with the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321478/prove-or-provide-a-counterexample-no-pair-of-primitive-pythagorean-triples-a?noredirect=1) indicates that there are no solutions in one case. Unfortunately, it's not an elementary solution. (It's also missing another case, due to forgetting about primitive solutions)

Comment: @WillJagy Can You review you comment well, There exist infinitely many primitive solution to the above Given Equation Not explicitly but by using the fact that every composite number pqr of the form 4k+1 can be written as a^2+b^2

Comment: And Why d=5? I am really confused what you said

Comment: Fact I used in $pqr$ is that $p\equiv q\equiv r\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ where all are primes. Now use fact of famous identity $(a^2+b^2)(u^2+v^2)=h^2+f^2$ which can be obtained by Gaussian integer split.

Comment: @HappieHappieHappie  let me not confuse you further. If you have an example, please display it by writing $a=$  and giving the specific value for $a,$  then same for $b,c,d$

Comment: @CalvinLin  thanks. I would guess the descent can be done in the manner of Mordell's book, the chapter on quartic equations with only trivial solutions. However, cannot be sure until all the details work out.

Comment: Actually values are critical to find But I have construction that told us that there are infinitely many values because for example $13\times 17\times 29=c$ is very large like that I can construct large solutions.Then there exist different $a, b, e, d$

Comment: @HappieHappieHappie I'm inclined to agree with Will here. Just state any solution that you've found, even if it's very large. $ c= 6409$ isn't too bad. $\quad$ However, I don't think there are corresponding integers $a, b, d$ that satisfy $6409^2 = a^2 +b^2 = d^2 + 4b^2$.

Comment: Okay I see Op Want's $b$ in 2 equations That I missed I thought it was, $c^2=a^2+b^2=d^2+4e^2$ that I missed. that there are two b's

Comment: My solution works if there are five distinct variable and not 4

Comment: I hope You got my point What I am trying to say. It's my careless ness to not look for equations properly I am sorry.

Comment: $a^2=u^2+3v^2$ which has A parameterization $a=m^2+3n^2$ $u=m^2-3n^2$ and $v=2mn$ there after we need $m^2+3n^2=g^2+f^2$ I think from here we can proceed.

Comment: What about $\pmod 3$ on last equation now?

Comment: It' has Solutions in $\mathbb{F}_3$ for sure

Comment: @HappieHappieHappie - the point you need to get is that if someone starts questioning your comment, it is wise to look deeply at what you've written before giving a flippant answer. It is even more wise when the person who is questioning is of high reputation (which you can see in comments by hovering the mouse over their signature) because they didn't get that reputation by being careless. And if their name is Will Jagy, it wiser still. To be sure, "look carefully, and correct if wrong" is all you should do, not back down when you are right. We all make mistakes. But tread with care.

Comment: Thank you, for letting me know,  I will follow.